# How to get attribute from bbcode [URL] tag using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
$string = '[URL="http://www.google.com"]Google[/URL]
```

I am using the following code to convert it to html link

```
$link = preg_replace('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/i', '<a href="\1">\2</a>', $string);
```

it converts it to the following format

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

That is OK. But I want to validate the both values `http://www.google.com` and `Google`, How can I get both the values separately with the Help of Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `preg_match`?

Actually, you can just use the pattern you already have. It will give you the whole match and each match within round parantheses through a parameter.

```
preg_match('/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/i', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // http://www.google.com
echo $matches[2]; // Google
echo $matches[0]; // [URL="http://www.google.com"]Google[/URL]
```

The return value of `preg_match` is 1 (match found) or 0/false (no match/error).